# How can i display posts on home page using loop in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using this code, I wanted to display 5 post on loop on home page but without changing homepage setting to "latest posts".

```
...
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-3,-8' );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
} else {
...
?>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in your theme's functions.php.
Use the shortcode. `[show_latest_posts]` in block editor Or  `<?php do_shortcode('[show_latest_posts]'); ?>`.

```
add_shortcode('show_latest_posts', 'zillion_latest_post_shortcode', 10);
function zillion_latest_post_shortcode(){

    ob_start();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=>5,
        'order'=>'DESC',
        'orderby'=>'ID',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
            echo '<div>'.get_the_content().'</div>';
        }

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Not working sir .. not showing any post on the front end.

Comment: where you are adding the shortcode? in a custom php page template on in a page editor?

Comment: custom php page template

Comment: then you should use `<?php do_shortcode('[show_latest_posts]'); ?>`.